# PHP if-statement being 'ignored', rendering both options

Tags: php, if-statement

So I am extremely new to PHP and am probably making a stupid mistake.  I have searched for quite a while, though, and have not been able to figure out what is going wrong.

Using XAMPP all of the PHP works fine.  When I load it onto my web server, however, the if statement regulating the log in form displays both the 'log in' form and the 'log out' form at the same time.  Obviously not what I want!

Here is the code snippet:

```
<?php
   if ( isset( $_SESSION['email'] ) ) { // Check to see if user is logged in.  If so, display log out button.
?>
    <form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="logout.php" method="POST">
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log Out</button>
    </form>
<?php 
   } else { // display log in form
?>
    <form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="login.php" method="POST">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="span2" placeholder="email">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="span2" placeholder="password">
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log In</button>
    </form>
<?php 
   } 
?>
```

This is contained in a file index.php

The basic logic is test to see if an email variable has been created for the session (done in a login.php execution) to check if the user is logged in.

I have no idea if this is the best way to create a log in, but that's what I've tried to do.

Again, I am very new to this, so any insight on where to look next would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: can you give us the raw HTML output of the page, or a link to the page where this is happening? In particular check to see if the PHP code itself is being outputted, which is a common result of web server misconfiguration.

Comment: Here is the website where it is happening:  www.lingual.me/index.php  It's a work in progress, don't judge! :P

Comment: Check the output and notice the raw php code there - it looks like your webserver is not running the PHP at all, which is your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a view source and make sure your PHP code is actually being interpreted. If you see your PHP tags in the source of the browser then your web server is not configured properly.

Comment: Or that the page isn't viewed on the localhost. I've seen that happen where someone forgot to view a file on localhost and it just showed html (and maybe some php?)

Comment: To expand, "your web server is not configured properly" means, are you sure your web server treats index.php as a php-file at all?

Comment: Okay, did the view-source and the PHP tags ARE showing up in the code.  How would I go about fixing my web server configuration? (more importantly, what should I fix?)

Comment: Also, login.php and logout.php seem to be working properly, as well as a separate function elsewhere in the website: subscribe.php.  Does this negate the idea that my web server is not configured for php?

Comment: I haven't run XAMPP here since I run Linux. You'll need to check the docs. Make sure your file ends in .php unless you've configured it otherwise. Make sure you are actually pulling the file through your web server and not directly from the disk (as mentioned above).

Comment: Noticed I never marked off a solution.  I ended up changing the PHP entirely. Thank you, though, I'll mark this as a fix!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(!empty( $_SESSION['email'] ))
```

and I hope you did session_start() at the beginning.

Comment: no change to the condition will fix this problem, because the problem isn't that the wrong one is being outputted, it's that _both_ are.

Comment: Actually, that is the condition I originally had.  I can change it back to that if that is a safer format.  I did not put session_start() at the beginning, actually...  That sounds important, what do I need to add at the beginning of the file?

Comment: just add <?php session_start() ?> at the very first line.

Comment: Okay I did that, the problem persists...  Feel free to check out the code at lingual.me/index.php

Comment: Your server did not understand PHP. The view source have the raw PHP code.

Comment: Okay well it is comforting to have a diagnosis!  So how would I fix that?  Also, three other files I am using: login.php, logout.php and subscribe.php all seem to be working properly, so I don't think it is a problem with my server's understanding of php in general...

Answer (score 0):

I think your *.php files does not behave like PHP files. You should check your web server settings.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use `echo`. Is it OK to try displying text without an `echo` statement before?